# Drag and drop using Selenium for Chrome without element Id's

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I have been searching the internet for ages now looking for a solution...

I am trying to simulate a drag and drop action in Chrome using Selenium WebDriver. This works in Firefox but not in Chrome due to a bug in Selenium as I'm sure you all know. The solutions I have managed to find so far have used javascript/jQuery and need the elements to have IDs.
However the element I want to drag and drop doesn't have an ID... the element has no unique identifiers.

What are the possible workarounds without having to get a dev to assign an ID in the HTML? As that isn't likely to happen any time soon.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Currently trying this:

```
js.ExecuteScript(jsReader + "$(document.querySelector('.example img')).simulateDragDrop({dropTarget: '#target'});");
```

Comment: No javascript/jQuery solution should require the elements to have IDs. They may make thing easier, but you should still be able to implement any of these solutions without having them. The hard part is finding a unique identifier. Play around in the chrome console until you are able to return just the element(s) you need

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the reply. I can locate the element using CSS selector. I'm using https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544

Comment: Why does a dev need to add the ID? Can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be this Chrome bug (just run into this myself) https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=841